# Getting calling the post content with variable in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When you are in worpdress, you can call the title of a post like the following:

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

How do you call its content?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `the_content`. More information in the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

Comment: cool thanks. But for some reason when i call the content, it spits it out all in one line, so the text is ontop of each other...

Comment: Try using `echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() )`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content

Comment: OK I see, there was a line-height applied by one of the parents, and it was inherited. thank you!